# How should I create databases for subsites?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I want to have a website that lets users create their own websites. Something like wordpress.com or drupalgardens.com .

My question is how should I create databases for users` websites? Should I create a seperate database for each user? Should I create a few databases and use different table prefixes for each user?

Does having thousands of databases cause performance problem?

Comment: In general, no - use one database and have a column on the relevant ones that marks who owns it. You'll find that you'll have some common tables that you'll want to join to user-specific ones, and then you'll need to get into cross-schema joins and whatnot - which can get a bit awkward.

Comment: would user have direct access to their database ???

Comment: Yes. they can export their database

Comment: An exception to my earlier comment might be if you are actually installing pre-written software like Drupal or Wordpress, where adding owner columns isn't feasible.

Comment: @halfer I'm using Drupal to create this site. So I can't change tables` structures. Drupal only has two options for databases: seperate database OR table prefix

Answer (score 4):

Create a database per user, it will make permission problems and namespacing bugs less likely, and will make you use mysql's permissions system like it was designed to. AFAIK this is how most shared hosting systems work.

If it wasn't for the overhead, I'd create a separate MySQL instance for each user, but then you're half way to virtualizing the whole system, and making it into a VPS :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a having a lot of tables, and are not worried for your users permissions: You can have one "master_table" which contains each website and it's unique id.
Based on that id you can create table prefixes like:

- 1234_settings
- 1234_users
- 5262_settings
- 5262_users

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, if you're feeling really clever, you can use a single Drupal installation and multiple databases with multi-site (google drupal multisite).

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you say